# how to loop questions from a file?

Tags: file, loops, import

how can ask my program to ask the questions from a word document (study guide) until they are all gone? the program i was provided with asks one of the questions but i need to be able to ask all of them, tell them when they got the answer wrong and deduct points starting from 5 deducting two every time they answer it wrong. **To be clear my question is how i can ask my program to pull questions from a document until there are none left by using a loop, then how can i deduct points for every time they get it wrong.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {     
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    HWData hd = new HWData();
  System.out.println(hd.getQuestion(0));
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("1. " + hd.getAnswer1(0));
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("2. " + hd.getAnswer2(0));
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("3. " + hd.getAnswer3(0));
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("4. " + hd.getAnswer4(0));

  int answer = input.nextInt();

  if (answer == hd.getCorrect(0))
  { System.out.println(" Great Job! You got the right answer!");}
  else
  { System.out.println(" You got the answer wrong, try again.");
    input.close();

  }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how HWData works. Without seeing that, we cannot answer the question. It looks like HWData is the piece which is actually pulling the questions from the document, but the code you have posted doesn't include that.

It looks like perhaps HWData allows you to retrieve different questions/answers by passing in a number to the getQuestion()/getAnswer()/getCorrect() methods.

If you are lucky, it also provides a way to find the total number of questions. In that case, you can probably do something like:

```
int currentScore = 5;

int numberOfQuestions = hd.getNumberOfQuestions();
for (int questionIndex=0; questionIndex<numberOfQuestions; ++questionIndex) {
    System.out.println(hd.getQuestion(questionIndex));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1. " + hd.getAnswer1(questionIndex));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("2. " + hd.getAnswer2(questionIndex));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("3. " + hd.getAnswer3(questionIndex));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("4. " + hd.getAnswer4(questionIndex));

    int answer = input.nextInt();

    if (answer == hd.getCorrect(questionIndex)) {
        System.out.println(" Great Job! You got the right answer!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(" You got the answer wrong.");
        currentScore -= 2;
    }
}

input.close();
System.out.println("Final score: " + currentScore);
```